# Functional test of A11y features

Tags: testing

Who has any experience with testing A11y features? I need to test focus and tabulation via keyboard.

How it works now in the browser:

1. Go via the tab key to link "Show more"
2. Press enter
3. Some content loaded via ajax
4. Press tab again and focus will be on the not expected element

What I tried to reproduce this situation in the tests:

// Focus to link

```
$this->getSession()->getPage()->findLink('Show more')->focus();
```

// Click to link

```
$this->getSession()->getPage()->clickLink('Show more');
```

// Get tag with focus

```
$has_focus = $this->getSession()->evaluateScript('document.activeElement.tagName');
```

After click on the link on the real site the focus is going to the body, but when I pressing Tab the focus is going to the 'Show more' link. I cant make it in the tests. I tried

// Press tab programmatically

```
$this->getSession()->getPage()->find('css', 'body')->keyUp(9);
```

// Press Enter to link to don't lost focus

```
$this->getSession()->executeScript(<<<JS
  jQuery('.pager-show-more a').focus().trigger({type: 'keyup', keyCode: 13});
JS);
```

Nothing to help.

The questions: how to press tab programmatically? How to click the link without lost the focus?

Update 1: I'm using chrome headless and WebDriverTestBase

Comment: If you aren't using a real browser, tests using Javascript aren't going to work. You need selenium and headless chrome for that, not just the default PHP client.

Comment: I'm using chrome headless and WebDriverTestBase

Comment: Is the test waiting for AJAX to finish? There are many variables here.